# Play a sound with silent mode iOS 5 and iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, ios6, ipod

I'm trying to test to play a song in with silence mode activate.

I have this code which I picked up from the answers in this web:

```
if(CFStringGetLength(state) == 0) {
    //SILENT
    NSLog(@"Silent switch is on");

    //create vibrate
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    //this 2 line below use to play audio even in silent/vibrator mode too

    UInt32 audioCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
    AudioSessionSetProperty( kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(UInt32), &audioCategory);

    NSError *error;

    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:soundPath] error:&error];
    [player play];
    NSLog(@"error %@",error);
}
else {
    //NOT SILENT
    NSLog(@"Silent switch is off");
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(finishedSound);
}
```

I'm testing in a iPod touch 4 generation ios 6 the sound sounds when the app is in background and foreground (with volume to a minimum).

But with iPad one with iOS 5.1.1 it doesn't sound none of two situations.

The sound sounds with the silence mode off in both devices.

Do you know what can I change to achieve that the app sounds in both situations ?

Comment: **I have this code which I picked up from the answers in this forum** D: oh the horror!! ! ! this is not a forum !